# Code for splitting worksheet into multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

Code for splitting worksheet into multiple worksheets.
But, here is the problem. When I run it. It give me blank sheets and doesn't put the data into those sheets.

Here is the code:

```
Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer
    vcol = 2
    Set ws = Sheets("AdHocReport_course (2)")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:Y1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next
    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear
    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Comment this out `On Error Resume Next` - do you get an error. And please, when posting code, **indent it** so it can be more easily read.

Comment: FWIW, the code works for me.  What sort of data do you have in column B?  Would any of the values not be valid when used as a worksheet name?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say if this is your issue but:

```
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
```

If you use default `Application.Evaluate` form of `Evaluate` then it will evaluate the formula in the context of the Activesheet: it would be safer to use the worksheet form:

```
If Not ws.Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
```

then it will use `ws` as the context.

Comment: I tried  If Not ws.Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then It just gave me more blank sheets.